# jqPlot show second based data not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqplot

I´m designing a Web page that has a jqGrid graph getting from MVC controller.

I cannot make jqPlot to plot correctly seconds data. It plot some data correctly (right side of graphics) but then it plots several points in the same X-Axis, which is not correct. I´ve drilled down the problem to the following code:

[EDIT]
Drilled down the problem.

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.json2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var line1 = [['2013-12-11 19:57.28', 10],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.27', 20],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.26', 30],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.25', 40],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.24', 50],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.23', 60],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.22', 70],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.21', 80],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.20', 90],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.19', 10],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.18', 20],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.17', 30],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.16', 40],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.15', 50],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.14', 60],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.14', 70],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.12', 80],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.11', 90],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.10', 10],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.09', 20],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.08', 30],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.07', 40],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.06', 50],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.05', 60],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.04', 70],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.03', 80],
                    ['2013-12-11 19:57.02', 90]];

        options = {
            title: 'Tendência Dados de Processo',
            height: 500,
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: -90,
                        fontSize: '8pt',
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%.2f',
                        fontSize: '8pt'
                    }
                }
            },
            cursor: {
                show: true,
                showVerticalLine: true,
                showTooltipDataPosition: true,
                cursorLegendFormatString: '%#d %H:%M:%S',

            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 's',
                xoffset: 20,
                yoffset: 20
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true
            }
        }

        var plot = $.jqplot('chart', [line1], options);

    });


</script>
```

jqPlot behaviour:

[image]

I don´t know what am I doing wrong, but I need to get this graph working fast. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input-dates needs to be in a standard format. jqPlot passes the values to `$.jsDate()`, which tries many different formats, but none of them allow a period to come between the minutes and seconds.

Change all the `.` to `:`, and it works:

```
var line1 = [['2013-12-11 19:57:28', 10],
             ['2013-12-11 19:57:27', 20],
             ['2013-12-11 19:57:26', 30],
             ['2013-12-11 19:57:25', 40],
             ['2013-12-11 19:57:24', 50],
             ['2013-12-11 19:57:23', 60],
             ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Keh/

Comment: Very, very tricky, but you are right. We don´t separate seconds using '.', but using ":" - probably it would take a while for me to figure this out - Thanks a lot. Got my credits!!!

Comment: Looking deeper, the sequence now is right, but I doesn´t plot correct X tick values. It shows instead of 19:57Hs X-Axis, an axis between 00:00 and 01:50Hs.

Comment: The tick format is chosen automatically to match the range of given values. If all the points are within the same hour, it will only show minutes and seconds. You can choose a tick-format yourself, by setting `formatString:'%#d %H:%M:%S'` in the tick options. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/R4Keh/1/